# Substracting JSON Web Token (JWT) with regular expression

Tags: regex, string, jwt

I'm trying to substract the value for the JWT and the value for the enviroment hashid from a long string that has this similar format.

{"user":{"hashId":"c45pq0","email":"info@whatever.com","name": "John Doe","company": null,"rights":[      "STATIC","USERS"]},"jwt":"**eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpcCI6InJvYkB3aXRodGhlZ3JpZC5jb20iLCJpA9qiOjE1Nzc3MTA5NjksImV4cCI6MTU4MDMwMjk2OSwiaXNzIjoid2l0aHRoZWdyaWQifQ.7PbwwsWU7x63Pd-J_KZQL22r185GfiufixyXQGOyQs8**","environment":{"hashId":"**abcd123**","name":"Doe"},"environmentRights": ["STATIC","USERS"]}

I'm interested in the bolded values. It could be two expressions or one.

I've tried this to isolate the JWT, but that doesn't work.
\bjwt\b,$
Basically I want the string that starts with jwt, and ends with the next comma after the jwt. But it doesn't work.

And I definitely don't know how to isolate the environment hashid value, considering there's more than one hashid value in the string.

Comment: What do you mean by "*substracting*"? Do you want to *extract* the value, or *remove* those properties from the JSON? In either case, you should not use regex for this. What programming language are you working with?

Comment: I'm using FME, which is a low code/no code application, which has the ability to use Regular expressions to process text. That's why my initial thought was to use regex. It also has the ability to implement Python scripts, so I will try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a regex solution (a regex solution is below):

The string appears to be valid `JSON` (that's why it's called a JSON Web Token). Parse it as `JSON` using the language of your choice. It should then be simple to extract whatever you want. For example, in Python:

```
import json

s = '{"user":{"hashId":"c45pq0","email":"info@whatever.com","name": "John Doe","company": null,"rights":[ "STATIC","USERS"]},"jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpcCI6InJvYkB3aXRodGhlZ3JpZC5jb20iLCJpA9qiOjE1Nzc3MTA5NjksImV4cCI6MTU4MDMwMjk2OSwiaXNzIjoid2l0aHRoZWdyaWQifQ.7PbwwsWU7x63Pd-J_KZQL22r185GfiufixyXQGOyQs8","environment":{"hashId":"abcd123","name":"Doe"},"environmentRights": ["STATIC","USERS"]}'

d = json.loads(s)
print(d['jwt'])
print(d['environment']['hashId'])
```

Prints:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpcCI6InJvYkB3aXRodGhlZ3JpZC5jb20iLCJpA9qiOjE1Nzc3MTA5NjksImV4cCI6MTU4MDMwMjk2OSwiaXNzIjoid2l0aHRoZWdyaWQifQ.7PbwwsWU7x63Pd-J_KZQL22r185GfiufixyXQGOyQs8
abcd123
```

In JavaScript:

```js
const s = '{"user":{"hashId":"c45pq0","email":"info@whatever.com","name": "John Doe","company": null,"rights":[ "STATIC","USERS"]},"jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpcCI6InJvYkB3aXRodGhlZ3JpZC5jb20iLCJpA9qiOjE1Nzc3MTA5NjksImV4cCI6MTU4MDMwMjk2OSwiaXNzIjoid2l0aHRoZWdyaWQifQ.7PbwwsWU7x63Pd-J_KZQL22r185GfiufixyXQGOyQs8","environment":{"hashId":"abcd123","name":"Doe"},"environmentRights": ["STATIC","USERS"]}'
const d = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(d.jwt);
console.log(d.environment.hashId);
```

**Regex Solution**

This regex may be a bit of an "overkill" where I am not assuming that a `"` cannot appear in in the `jwt` or `hashId` fields (properly escaped, of course). Some research on my part could answer that question, but ...

```
"jwt":\s*"((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)".*?"hashId":\s*"((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)"
```

1. `"jwt":\s*"` Matches "jwt": followed by 0 or more whitespace characters followed by ".
2. `((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)` Matches 0 or more characters as long as they are not a " character not preceded by a backslash and accumulates these characters in capture group 1.
3. `"` matches ".
4. `.*?` Non-greedily matches 0 or more non-newline characters until ...
5. `"hashId":\s*"` Matches "hashId": followed by 0 or more whitespace characters followed by ".
6. `((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)` Matches 0 or more characters as long as they are not a " character not preceded by a backslash and accumulates these characters in capture group 2.
7. `"` matches ".

Values you want are in capture groups 1 and 2.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iUgSDY/3/)

```
import re

s = '{"user":{"hashId":"c45pq0","email":"info@whatever.com","name": "John Doe","company": null,"rights":[ "STATIC","USERS"]},"jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpcCI6InJvYkB3aXRodGhlZ3JpZC5jb20iLCJpA9qiOjE1Nzc3MTA5NjksImV4cCI6MTU4MDMwMjk2OSwiaXNzIjoid2l0aHRoZWdyaWQifQ.7PbwwsWU7x63Pd-J_KZQL22r185GfiufixyXQGOyQs8","environment":{"hashId":"abcd123","name":"Doe"},"environmentRights": ["STATIC","USERS"]}'

m = re.search(r'"jwt":\s*"((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)".*?"hashId":\s*"((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)"', s)
if m:
    print(m[1])
    print(m[2])
```

Prints:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpcCI6InJvYkB3aXRodGhlZ3JpZC5jb20iLCJpA9qiOjE1Nzc3MTA5NjksImV4cCI6MTU4MDMwMjk2OSwiaXNzIjoid2l0aHRoZWdyaWQifQ.7PbwwsWU7x63Pd-J_KZQL22r185GfiufixyXQGOyQs8
abcd123
```